# How to install a latex editor with "native" TeXLive installation already in place on Ubuntu?

Tags: texlive, installing, editors, linux, tlmgr

After hours wasted trying to work with the Ubuntu repository version of `TeXLive` (`tlmgr` wasn't working), I installed the "native" version of `TeXLive` (2017, via "Quick Installer" from the [official site](http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html)) and `tlmgr` was now functional.

However, when I go ahead and install `TexMaker` from the Ubuntu repository, it rolls out its own (outdated) version of `TeXLive`. I've been trying to install from binaries on TeXMaker's [site](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/), but the site is down.

So then I tried installing `TeXstudio`, [downloaded](https://texstudio.org/) the appropriate binary (Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit QT5) and installed it via Software Center, but seemingly I'm getting things I never wanted. E.g. the "native" `TeXLive`'s `tlmgr` was in `/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux` folder, after installing `TeXstudio` now it's "shadowed" by `/usr/bin`. It's also a version that is 2 years behind the current `tlmgr` from the official site.

How to install a TeX editor so that it doesn't roll out its own TexLive installation or `tlmgr`?

Comment: maybe creating a "fake package" (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/36296) can help.

Comment: Your question is OS specific and I think that you had to use backports in Ubuntu (but I am not sure about that)... I think you have to add "linux" or simmilar tag to your question and ububtu in your title to have more chances to find an answer

Comment: @koleygr Ubuntu was already among the tags, I've replaced it with linux. Thanks for mentioning. I'm not sure what you mean by 'backports'. I've used TeXLive's tl-installer, that isn't very OS specific apart from Linux in general.

Comment: @TeXnophobe, sorry, I didn't  show the tag.. I suppose it was ok... google for "ubuntu 16.04 texlive backports" and I am sure that you will see what I mean. Backports is the way to get newer than official supported packages on ubuntu

Comment: @samcarter Thank you, I'm trying to apply the "Fake packages" section from the linked answer.

Comment: you can download `texstudio` from the official site and then to install it using command line (`cd ~\the folder you download the file--> sudo dpkg -i the file`). Also, there is this script from which you can download `texlive` for ubuntu https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu

Comment: alternative, `miktex` now supports ubuntu as well. i tried it in the past without any (major) problem

Comment: Exactly how did you install texstudio? If you install via the command line, you can give apt the option `--no-install-recommends` (look it up in the man page for at, not sure I spelled it correctly), then recommend additions will not be installed. Besides this just making and installing the equivs tl package will also be a good idea (I'm guessing that is what samcarters link describes, otherwise the page i always use can be found via a Google on "texlive vanilla Debian"

Comment: @Yorgos Initially I was happy about MikTeX and installed it, but it seems to be very-very slow on Ubuntu (no idea what's the exact reason), I need to use xelatex (because of Chinese) and it takes minutes to compile just the 5 line test .tex file to verify installation. There must be something horribly wrong here.

Comment: @Yorgos already provided a solution. The concept: If you use apt or apt-get, then whatever you wish to install will also install support (recommended) packages, which will be from the Ubutnu texlive distribution (not what you want). It does not detect your existing manual texlive intsllation. So instead, you download TeXStudio from its own web site. Then, you install the downloaded installer via `dpkg -i`, not apt. You may need to force install. Then launch the program via Terminal command line. If any necessary packages are missing, note what they are (as long as they are not texlive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the input in the comments.

Here's what worked for me.

My **system**: Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) 64-bit

What I **installed**:

First I downloaded the "Quick Installer" from [`TeXLive`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) and proceeded as recommended. I uncompressed the archive, ran the installer with `sudo ./install-tl` from the folder. It took a looong time to "quick install" all the 3500+ packages.

Then I installed `TeXstudio` with `sudo apt-get install texstudio --no-install-recommends`. (Thanks @daleif for mentioning the flag.)

After TeXstudio was installed, I launched the application. It prompted me with a warning about not having a TeX installation. I went to `Options > Configure TeXstudio...` and in `Commands` set the path to `xelatex` pointing to the TeXLive installation and then in `Build` set the Default compiler to `xelatex` (which is the compiler I'll mostly need, proceed similarly for other compilers of your choice).

Now the TeX installation seems to be OK. Feel free to point out potential pitfalls or anything.

The other suggested workarounds either failed at one point or are beyond my level of "expertise" and willingness to manage a system with hacks and tricks (I won't remember them by the time I need to change something).

Comment: The options configure should not be needed if you added the texlive path to the right configuration file. It usually goes into `.profile` (you need to log out and in again to activate it). If you added the path addition to bashrc, and you open texstudio from a menu, texstudio never runs bash and never sees the path change